# How do I assign values to checkboxes dynamically through jsf?

Tags: java, jsf

I've tried the following:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{example.allValues}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{example.values}" />
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
</h:form>
```

but its not showing the values..

Here is my bean:

```
public class Example {
    private List<String> allValues;
    private List<String> values;

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Inside INIT");
        values = new ArrayList<String>();
        values.add("ABC");
        values.add("XYZ");
        values.add("PQR");
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public List<String> getAllValues() {
        return allValues;
    }

    public void setAllValues(List<String> allValues) {
        this.allValues = allValues;
    }
}
```

Please tell me what i've done wrong.. Thanks

Comment: How do you invoke the `init()` method? Is it annotated by `@PostConstruct` or you mean to use `<f:viewAction>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to annotate the `init()` method `PostConstruct`, otherwise it won't be invoked. Also, the class has to be annotated with `@ManagedBean`:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Example {
    //..     

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       //..
    }
}
```

Comment: @Learner Please mark this answer accepted to close this question. How we thank each other here